# how to validate selected <t:selectBooleanCheckbox> in jsf?

Tags: javascript, validation, jsp, jsf, tomahawk

i have a group of   t:selectBooleanCheckbox which are retrieved from the backing bean , which are from database .

how to make a java script validation to check that 
if all these check boxes is checked , then go and check another specific checkbox .

Comment: client-side it is all html (and javascript) and it is hence not jsp, not jsf and only slightly tomahawk related.

Answer (score -1):

try adding `required="true"` to checkboxes